# How to handle play orders

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on 2 players game using flutter and dart language, and create a queue collection contains all players who want to play so I want to sort every two player in new collection.

I thought might there is a way in the rules of cloud firestore, is there ?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Firestore security rules control who has (read and/or write) access to the data. The security can in no way modify the data on their own. If you want to create a new collection, you will need to write code for that that uses one of the Firestore SDKs or the REST API.